# Meteor error - promise.js

Tags: meteor

I have a reoccuring problem with my meteor applications that has caused me to delete and redo all my projects.  The problem is that whenever I go to start up my app with `meteor run` or `meteor` it shows this error:

[image]

I had this problem with another one of my app and it required me to uninstall meteor and reinstall it for it to work..I was wondering if there was any other way to fix this problem.  Many people have said delete you `.meteor` folder or `.meteor/local` folder and start it up again but that has not worked for me.  Another solution that has worked for many people except me is the command that you run inside your application `rm -rf ./.meteor` but I have no luck with that.  I don't know what to do at this point in terms of fixing my problem.  and I do not have a problem with my code, as it was working about 2 days ago and I haven't touched it since.

I have:

- Windows 10 Pro.
- 64 bit operating system(I don't know if that matters).
- Meteor v1.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stuart,

Deleting the `.meteor` folder isn't a good idea, because it contains the list of packages, and your project won't work at all then.

You can delete `.meteor/local`, because that is basically its temporary build area. Another thing you can do it delete the `node_modules` folder, or type `npm rebuild` which tells npm to rebuild the `node_modules` directory in case there is some corruption in there.

meteor reset will clear out your database in case that is the problem.
You can delete`~/.meteor`, where ~ is your home directory. Meteor will rebuild it.

As for the screen shot, it's better if you can paste the actual text here, because I can't tell what that character is it's complaining about. Remember to click the button with the braces to format it correctly.

Hopefully one of the above will help you. Otherwise perhaps you could share the project?

Comment: Thanks I did meteor reset and deleted the node_modules folder and rebuilt it like you said.  And about the photo, I am on windows and it does not let me highlight and copy and paste on the command line, so I thought an image would be my only option.

Comment: Excellent, glad to know you back in action. You can cut and paste from the windows command line, there are menu options for it, although it's not intuitive at all. ConEmu is a good replacement - that's what I use if I have to be on Windows https://conemu.github.io/